# Como enviar um post para uma API AspNetCore sem converter o data usando Json.Stringify

Tags: asp.net-core

Olá, estou começando a trabalhar com ASPNET Core e há um problema na lógica de trabalho que não consigo aceitar (entendo como um pensamento burro mesmo). Vamos aos exemplos:

> **NOTA:** em todos os testes estou usando a biblioteca jQuery para facilitar o entendimento.

Se eu trabalhar com um webserver ExpressJS (Node.JS), em um post simples para o servidor, eu posso fazer uma requisição ajax como esta:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"api/foo",
    method:"post",
    data:{bar:123},    // <-- objeto sem serializar
    success:function(res){console.log(res);},
    error:function(res){console.log(res);}
});
```

No caso, não é necessário transformar o objeto do parâmetro `data` em uma string, usando o recurso `data:JSON.stringify({bar:123})`.

Isso também ocorre com outros frameworks em PHP que já trabalhei (como o laravel, codeigniter, zend, etc).

Agora, se eu tenho uma solução ASPNET Core, sou obrigado a fazer minha requisição dessa forma:

**Request vindo do front-end da solução**

```
$.ajax({
    url:"api/foo",
    method:"post",
    contentType:"application/json;charset=utf8", // <-- excesso de código desnecessário
    data:JSON.stringify({bar:123}),              // <-- excesso de código desnecessário
    success:function(res){console.log(res);},
    error:function(res){console.log(res);}
});
```

**Controlador no back-end da solução**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AppTest.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class FooController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Post([FromBody] object req)
        {
            return Json(req);
        }
    }
}
```

Pergunta 1 - Existe, alguma forma de que eu consiga obrigar o ASPNET Core a **SEMRPE** aceitar o objeto sem que eu tenha que fazer a serialização do mesmo no meu front-end?

Pergunta 2 - Tem como eu configurar a solução para que ele sempre receba o contentType do tipo "application/json"? (Isso do lado do servidor e não no front-end...)

Comment: Por que você está usando object como parâmetro da sua action? Tentar criar uma classe e passar com as propriedades do JSON que vai funcionar sem precisar do JSON.stringify no client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim como o Thiago Silva disse, Eu realmente precisei criar uma classe com os métodos que seriam apropriados para conseguir relacionar o conteúdo que vai ser postado. Como vim de Javascript onde podemos ter elementos genéricos, pensei que, utilizando `object` eu teria o mesmo comportamento (o que não vem ao caso)... Minha solução ficou assim:

**Uma nova classe: FooModel**

```
namespace AppTest.Models {
    class FooModel {
        string bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Implementar a classe no código existente**

```
using AppTest.Models;

namespace AppTest.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class FooController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Post([FromBody] FooModel req)
        {
            return Json(req);
        }
    }
}
```

Por trabalhar com C# que é uma linguagem extremamente tipada, tenho que definir antes o tipo do elemento de entrada, senão ela não consegue interpretar e fazer o parse correto do json...